# question about sigma algebra generated by a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question. If I have a sigma algebra $\sigma(X_1)$ generated by $X_1$ where $X_1 \subset 2^P $ .  And say $X_2$ is another sigma algebra where $X_2 \subset 2^P $.

I was reading that if $X_1$ is contained in $\sigma(X_2)$, then automatically $\sigma(X_1)$ is contained in $\sigma(X_2)$. But I am not sure why.

Could someone explains?

Comment: So $\sigma(X_{2})$ is also a SIGMA algebra containing $X_{1}$, and $\sigma(X_{1})$ is the SMALLEST (in the sense of inclusion) algebra containing $X_{1}$.

Comment: Yes every book that I read says $\sigma(X_1)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that contains $X_1$, but may I know why if $X_1$ is in $\sigma(X_2)$ then automatically $\sigma (X_1)$ is also in $\sigma (X_2)$?

Comment: The point is that, do you know what the smallest is meant to be?

Comment: First of all $X_{1}\in\sigma(X_{1})$ and $X_{1}\in\sigma(X_{2})$. And we can compare $\sigma(X_{1})$ and $\sigma(X_{2})$, but $\sigma(X_{1})$ being the smallest, so $\sigma(X_{1})\subseteq\sigma(X_{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is see:

$\sigma(X_{1})=\displaystyle\bigcap\{P: P~\text{is a}~\sigma-\text{algebra that containing}~X_{1}\}$. Now $\sigma(X_{2})\in\bigcap\{P: P~\text{is a}~\sigma-\text{algebra that containing}~X_{1}\}$, so $\sigma(X_{1})\subseteq\sigma(X_{2})$.

Comment: Hi, but when it says $\sigma(X_1)$ is in the intersection of ALL sigma algebra that contains $X_1$, could it be true that only part of the $\sigma(X_1)$ is in $\sigma(X_2)$? i.e. it might not be true that the whole set of $\sigma(X_1)$ is in $\sigma(X_2)$?

Comment: because the P is a sigma algebra that contains $X_1$, it doesn't say P is a sigma algebra that contains $\sigma(X_1)$. I thought the consequence that a set say P containing $X_1$ is totally different from when it contains $\sigma(X_1)$.

Comment: also may I know what you mean in your second sentence here when you say $\sigma(X_2)$ is an element in the intersection of .....

Comment: I guess I might not understand what "smallest" mean. Maybe this could clarify my understanding. If I have some sigma algebra say $X_3$ and $X_4$, and both $\sigma(X_3)$ and $\sigma(X_4)$ contains $X_1$, but the number of set in $\sigma(X_4)$ is bigger than $\sigma(X_3)$, does it mean I will have $\sigma(X_1) \subset \sigma(X_3) \subset \sigma(X_4)$?